# Floating a list to the right

Tags: html, css

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/gxLt5/11/

I thought by using a `float:right` with the class: `right` the account list item (test test) would sit on the far with of the purple bar, but instead it doesn't.

Can anyone explain what I have done wrong please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `ul`'s `width` is less than you've expected (it does not take the rest of the space). You can have a workaround with `calc` applied to the `.navigation` :

```
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

*P.S.* : `100px` is a hardcoded value, so it depends on the `width` of the `a` with the `img`.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxLt5/14/)

Another solution is to push link with `img` in the list and set it's `width` to `100%`. Then set `float:left` to the fist *n-1* `li` and `float:right` to the last.

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxLt5/20/)

Comment: It seems quite messy like this. Is it not a better solution to include the image in the list or instead make it a separate list on the right?

Comment: @Jimmy : Yes, like this.I've posted the exact same thing)))

Comment: @Jimmy: I've meant example in the comments)

Comment: Ah! Ok I see. It pushes the list items down though with this approach?

Comment: Using calc is not a solution because it doesn`t have a good browser support.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gxLt5/22/ - solution without using calc and using display: table-cell instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's floating to the right of it's parent element which is navigation, which doesn't stretch the whole width of the purple bar.

Give navigation 100% width and work it out from there.

Comment: It pushes it off the end though in that case: http://jsfiddle.net/gxLt5/13/embedded/result/

Comment: yeah because navigation needs to be less than 100%, that's why I said work it out from there.

Answer (score 1):

it **does** float right, that is to the right edge of your `ul` element. But since it's not the entire width of your purple bar, it does not appear to float right.

Comment: @Jimmy that's when you give it too much width. Set it to around 80%, that seems to do it.